# Wrong mass center point (opencv and moment function)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the mass center of images using OpenCV and I got errors, as you can see in the images (the mass center must not be to closest of any side in this cases). Also, I got mass centers that depends of the rotation and that's incorrect.

Next, you can see the code, input image and output image.

I tried with different example codes, and the results are the same.

Output image: [Mass center calculated by the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcPS.png)
Input image: [Image Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh30O.png)

Example code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat srcGray;
RNG rng(12345);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread(argv[1], 1);

    // Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, srcGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(srcGray, srcGray, Size(3, 3));

    Mat srcThresh;
    double otsu;

    otsu = threshold(srcGray, srcThresh, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    Mat cannyOut;
    Canny(srcGray, cannyOut, otsu, otsu * 1 / 2, 3, 1);

    // Find contours
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(cannyOut, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    // Get the moments
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);
    }

    //  Get the mass centers:
    vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
    }

    // Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(cannyOut.size(), CV_8UC3);
    string sObjectNumber;          // string which will contain the result
    ostringstream sContourNumber;   // stream used for the conversion

    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
//        drawing.setTo(Scalar(0.0,0.0,0.0));
        sContourNumber << i;
        sObjectNumber = sContourNumber.str();   // Convert int to string
        Point pCoordinates(mc[i].x + 3, mc[i].y - 3);   // Text's coordinates (A little bit off from mass center)
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        circle(drawing, mc[i], 4, color, -1, 8, 0);     // Draw mass center
        putText(drawing, sObjectNumber, pCoordinates, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, color, 2, 8); // Write object number
        sContourNumber.str("");     // Clear string
        sContourNumber.clear();     // Clear any error flags

//        imshow("Contours", drawing);
//        waitKey();
    }

    double hu[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Contour: " << i << " Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << " Length: " << arcLength(contours[i], true) << "\n";

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            HuMoments(mu[i], hu);
            cout << "Contour: " << i << " Hu: " << j << " Result: " << hu[j] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    imshow("Contours", drawing);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

Very thanks for all!
Diego

Comment: Suggestion: reduce your code to one fixed contour with a known center of mass to test your algorithm and keep working the code until you compute the answer you expect. if you can solve the problem, awesome. If you can't, you have a [mcve] and a good place to start asking questions.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer! It is interesting your suggestion. I tried to do that, I just have tested various versions of code that uses these functions and I have submitted one, there is other (same results): http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html. I posted an image with various triangles because I cannot submit various image input, and I have verified that if I try with an image with only one triangle, the results are the same. Some clarification about the waited results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#/media/File:Triangle.Centroid.svg

Comment: You should compute the moments on a _filled_ blob, not just the contour